# How to show only scoped instances of Task model in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm building a Task Manager in Rails.  I used scope to get all instances of a Task model that are due today.  The scope on the Task model works and is returning only Tasks due today when calling due_today on Tasks in the Rails console.  But I can't seem to show these Tasks due today in the view.  Do I need to add a conditional?

This is my views index.html.erb

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Team's Tasks</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date assigned</th>
      <th>Due date</th>
      <th>Overdue?</th>
      <th>Completed?</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.title %></td>
        <td><%= task.description %></td>
        <td><%= task.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= task.duedate %></td>
        <td><%= task.overdue? %></td>
        <td><%= task.completed %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<h1>Tasks due today.</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task title</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date assigned</th>
      <th>Due date</th>
      <th>Overdue?</th>
      <th>Completed?</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.due_today.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.title %></td>
        <td><%= task.description %></td>
        <td><%= task.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= task.duedate %></td>
        <td><%= task.overdue? %></td>
        <td><%= task.completed %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
</p>
```

this is my Task model

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  #use scope on Task model to mark overdue Tasks if the present date is greater than duedate.
  scope :overdue, -> { where("duedate < ?", Time.now) }
  #use scope on Task model to get only tasks that are due today.
  scope :due_today, ->{ where("duedate >= ? AND duedate <= ?", Date.current.beginning_of_day, Date.current.end_of_day) }

end
```

This is the controller

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_task, only: %i[ show edit update destroy ]

  # GET /tasks or /tasks.json
  # Order all tasks by ascending order
  def index
    @tasks = Task.all.order(duedate: :asc)
  end

  # GET /tasks/1 or /tasks/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /tasks/new
  def new
    @task = Task.new
  end

  # GET /tasks/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /tasks or /tasks.json
  def create
    @task = Task.new(task_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.save
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: "Task was successfully created." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :new, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /tasks/1 or /tasks/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @task.update(task_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @task, notice: "Task was successfully updated." }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @task }
      else
        format.html { render :edit, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        format.json { render json: @task.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /tasks/1 or /tasks/1.json
  def destroy
    @task.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to tasks_url, notice: "Task was successfully destroyed." }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
        # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.

    def set_task
      @task = Task.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Only allow a list of trusted parameters through.
    def task_params
      params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :duedate, :completed)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Got it to work. No changes to the controller. None needed.  This is the code.

This is the Task model.

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
  #use scope on Task model to mark overdue Tasks if the present date is greater than duedate.
  scope :overdue, -> { where("duedate < ?", Time.now) }
  #use scope on Task model to get Tasks due today.
  scope :due_today, ->{ where("duedate >= ? AND duedate <= ?", Date.current.beginning_of_day, Date.current.end_of_day) }

  def overdue?
    duedate < Time.now
  end

  def due_today?
    duedate >= Date.current.beginning_of_day && duedate <= Date.current.end_of_day
  end

end
```

This is the Task view.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>

<h1>Team Task Manager</h1>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date assigned</th>
      <th>Due date</th>
      <th>Overdue?</th>
      <th>Completed?</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.title %></td>
        <td><%= task.description %></td>
        <td><%= task.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= task.duedate %></td>
        <td><%= task.overdue? %></td>
        <td><%= task.completed %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>
<br>

<h1>DUE TODAY!</h1>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Task</th>
      <th>Description</th>
      <th>Date assigned</th>
      <th>Due date</th>
      <th>Overdue?</th>
      <th>Completed?</th>
      <th colspan="3"></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>
    <% @tasks.due_today.each do |task| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= task.title %></td>
        <td><%= task.description %></td>
        <td><%= task.created_at %></td>
        <td><%= task.duedate %></td>
        <td><%= task.overdue? %></td>
        <td><%= task.completed %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Show', task %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Edit', edit_task_path(task) %></td>
        <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', task, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<p>
  <%= link_to 'New Task', new_task_path %>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have a TasksController and an index method there.

try following in the index method

```
def index
  @tasks = Task.due_today
end
```

let me know if this works

Comment: can you update question with controller code as well?

Comment: Updated.  Keep in mind i want to show all tasks, and only tasks due today in index.html.erb

Answer (score 0):

You need to change **due_date** scope.. use between or date_trunc method.

where("date_trunc('day', duedate)::date = ?", Date.today)

let me know if it works